# Infer wire labels for bus from package connection in Proteus

Tags: proteus

As far as I can tell, to use a bus in Proteus you need to manually assign a label to each connection (as you can see for PA[0..3] here).

[image: Screenshot]

Often, these wire labels are going to be the same as the package they connect to (at least on the source end). Is there any way to auto-generate or infer these?

It's just a pain to have to do it for every single connection mannually.

Comment: you can use tools->property assignment tool